# Create an Array of Specific Custom Post Meta

Tags: custom-field, array

I'm having an issue thinking today and ran into a brick wall.

What I'm trying to do it take 3 different custom field data for posts and combine them into an array that I can then json encode for use in some jquery.

The three fields I want to use are the 'project title' and a custom field of 'latitude' and 'longitude'. And this is what I'm looking to get:

Array ([0] => array ([0] => "project title", [1] => "latitude", [2] => "longitude"),[1] => array ([0] => "post title", [1] => "latitude", [2] => "longitude")

I'm thinking i need a foreach loop, but just can't get it to work in my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, and if by 'project title' you mean the content of the `post_title` field, then it'll look something like this:

```
$post_data = array();

$my_query = new WP_Query( $whatever_your_args_are );
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        $post_data[] = array(
            'project_title' => get_the_title(),
            'latitude'      => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true ),
            'longitude'     => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true )
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode( $post_data );
```

I changed your example just a touch so that the JSON object would have the values keyed nicely (`project_title`, `latitude`, `longitude`) instead of the more opaque numerical keys. I'm also assuming that you're using `WP_Query` to query and loop through the posts. If not, you can replace the `WP_Query` stuff with a loop over whatever content you've pulled from the DB.

Comment: Boom! You're the brain kick I needed this morning! Thanks, Boone!

Comment: Cha-cha-cha-ching!